# Delete columns/rows with NaN with apply

Tags: r, apply

So, I have the following matrix m:

```
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
    v1    0    1    2    3    3
    v2    1    1   NaN   4    4
    v3    2    2    2    3    4
    v4   NaN   3    3    4    5
    v5    4   NaN   4    5    5
```

and I need to eliminate the columns (and rows) that have NaN.
I found several easy ways to do it, like:

```
m[,!is.nan(colSums(m))]
```

for columns, but I want to use apply.

I tried using this (sol 1):

```
m[,!is.nan(apply(m,1,sum))]
```

but it shows me the first two columns.

I finally came up with this (sol 2):

```
m2[,!as.logical(colSums(-apply(m2, 2, is.nan)))]
```

But I think that solution is not that elegant.

Is there a way to make it shorter? 
Also, why does my first solution not work?

Comment: Why do you want to use `apply` when the first method is better?

Comment: I am learning R, I am trying different ways of solving the same problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To practice with `apply` functions, remember that the comma placement matters.

```
m[,!is.nan(apply(m, 2, sum))]
   [,1] [,2]
v1    3    3
v2    4    4
v3    3    4
v4    4    5
v5    5    5

m[!is.nan(apply(m, 1, sum)),]
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
v1    0    1    2    3    3
v3    2    2    2    3    4
```

Comment: You're right! I had a good solution but I mixed up columns and rows. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
m[!is.na(rowSums(m)),!is.na(colSums(m))]
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to sum

```
m <- matrix(c(  
  0,    1,    2,    3,    3,
  1,    1,   NaN,   4,    4,
  2,    2,    2,    3,    4,
  NaN,   3,    3,    4,    5,
  4,   NaN,   4,   5,    5), 5, byrow=TRUE)
m[!apply(is.na(m),1,any), !apply(is.na(m),2,any)]
```

or (if you want the other result) with `is.nan()` in the place of `is.na()`

Comment: That is shorter indeed. What does 'any' do?

Comment: the value `any(x)` is `TRUE` if one element of `x` is `TRUE`